# Cannot run npm in cron jobs

Tags: node.js, npm, cron

```
which npm



/Users/rnd/.npm-packages/bin/npm


* * * * *  cd ~/doc | /Users/rnd/.npm-packages/bin/npm test  >/tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log


output: 

env: node: No such file or directory
```

If i run exact same command in terminal, it works perfectly. What should i do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cd ~/doc && ` to run both in sequence? Also why would you have to run npm via cron? Just curious

Comment: You need to see what user is used in `cron` here. `sudo crontab -e` is `root` while `crontab -e` is `whoami`. Run the command as the same user and see if it still works.